# How to bind a wpf combobox to a DataTable - but do not show duplicate values

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox, datatable

Having some trouble figuring this out. So I have a simple combobox, and I bind it to an existing DataTable in the code-behind like so:

```
roomCombo.ItemsSource = ((IListSource) myDataTable).GetList();
roomCombo.DisplayMemberPath = "Number";
```

The combobox shows everything i have in the Number column, including duplicates, of course. I'm looking for a way to show only unique values ..

Thanks.

Comment: `roomCombo.ItemsSource = ((IListSource) myDataTable).GetList().Distinct().ToList()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a good way to do this:

```
DataView view = new DataView(myDataTAble);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, columnName);
```